# Python Selenium: How can I print the link?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

How can I print the value of the href attribute?

```
<a href="aaaaa.pdf"></a>
```

How can I print the link `aaaaa.pdf` with python selenium?

HTML:

```
<div class="xxxx">
    <a href="aaaaa.pdf"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.xxxx a
```

first, check if this `CSS_SELECTOR` is representing the desired element.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If yes, then use explicit waits:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
print(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xxxx a"))).get_attribute('href'))
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```py
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".xxxx a").get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, None, output.

Comment: ```print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".xxxx > a").get_attribute('href'))``` or ```print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".xxxx a").get_attribute('href')) ```sorry, I forgot the anchor tag

Comment: no problem :), output "https://xxxxx.com  › xxxx..." not link, its a text.. I want link. Thank you for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
   pName = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".xxxx").text
    print(pName)
```

or

```
   pName = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".xxxx").get_attribute("href")
   print(pName)
```

Comment: Hello, None, it output.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the *`href`* attribute i.e. ***aaaaa.pdf*** is within the `<a>` tag which is the only descendant of the `<div>` tag.

---

### Solution

To print the value of the *`href`* attribute you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xxxx > a").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='xxxx']/a").get_attribute("href"))
  ```

To extract the value ideally you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xxxx > a"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='xxxx']/a"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```