# How can I print more links from the HTML DOM using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, getattribute

Html:

```
<div class="xxxx">
<a href="ooooo.pdf"></a>
</div>
```

Python selenium code trials:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
print(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xxxx a"))).get_attribute('href'))
```

Output:

```
aaaaa.pdf
```

How print `ooooo.pdf` and `aaaaa.pdf`?

I want to print more links, what should I do?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759787/fetch-all-href-link-using-selenium-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch all href link using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759787/fetch-all-href-link-using-selenium-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) returns a single WebElement hence *`href`* attribute of only the first matching element is printed.

---

### Solution

To extract all the *`href`* attribute values you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xxxx a")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='xxxx']//a")))])
  ```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can also try:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xxxx a")])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='xxxx']//a")])
  ```

Comment: thank you okay. so what should i do?

Comment: @ADAM Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: eror :(

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: But the same CSS `div.xxxx a` seems to have worked for your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71938299/7429447) for which you have accepted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71938845/7429447)

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you so muck its a work! but webcache.googleusercontent.com I came across something like this, how can I not reflect it on the screen?

Comment: @ADAM I have to look into the issue in details. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.